# Know which Lambda has used DynamoDB the most

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

In my AWS account, I have several Lambda.

During this month, I had a little extra cost for DynamoDB (AWS Cost Explorer):

[image]

I would like to know which Lambda has used DynamoDB services the most times (e.g. RCUs and WCUs).

I tried with Lambda Metrics in CloudWatch but I didn't get anything relative to DynamoDB:

[image]

Can you give me some advice please?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: That is not something you can analyze after the fact unless you explicitly logged information about that in every lambda function invocation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

If I understood correctly, I would have to write a message in my logs each time when my Lambdas call the DynamoDB service to be able to easily search with Logs Insights?

Comment: Yes, if each lambda logged each request and you include the RCU / WCU in that log then you could analyse it

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the value of the RCU or WCU after a call to one of the DynamoDB Client functions (like putItem https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-dynamodb-2012-08-10.html#putitem , getItem etc.)?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the documentation you linked there are various segments about "consumed capacity" which include configuring what output you want and explaining what the output would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by @luk2302:

I added this key of each request:

```
ReturnConsumedCapacity
ReturnItemCollectionMetrics
```

Now, in Log Insights, I can make this query:

```
fields
@timestamp,
TableName,
Method,
ItemCollectionKey.__partitionKey.S as partitionKey,
CapacityUnits as TotalCapacityUnits,
Table.CapacityUnits as Table,
LocalSecondaryIndexes.LSIGeneric1.CapacityUnits as __LSI_1,
LocalSecondaryIndexes.LSIGeneric2.CapacityUnits as __LSI_2,
LocalSecondaryIndexes.LSIGeneric3.CapacityUnits as __LSI_3,
LocalSecondaryIndexes.LSIGeneric4.CapacityUnits as __LSI_4,
LocalSecondaryIndexes.LSIGeneric5.CapacityUnits as __LSI_5
| filter @message like /ConsumedCapacity/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Result:

[image]

Now, I'm looking for Log Insights queries allowing me to group my results by:

```
Method
```

OR

```
SUM OF TotalCapacityUnits GROUPED BY Method AND partitionKey
```